# A property for some finite groups (especially ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and consider the following property:

**(P)** for every factorization
 $n=ab$ there exist subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|=a$, $|B|=b$ and $G=AB$.

($AB=\{ab:a\in A, b\in B\}$)

Note. If $G$ has the property that for every divisor $d$ of $n$  there exists a subgroup of $G$ with order $d$ or $n/d$, then we can show that $G$ enjoys **(P)**.

Therefore, **(P)** is true for all finite abelian groups, and also one can check that the groups $S_n$, $A_n$ and ${\rm PSL}(2,n)$, where $n\leq 8$, have the property.

Now, is **(P) true for** ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$?

(we think this is a good candidate for a probable counterexample.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you check a group, say $\operatorname{PSL}(2, 7)$, enjoys **(P)**?

Comment: Indeed, we use this fact that: if $G$ has a subgroup of prime index enjoying (P),
then so is $G$.

Comment: Also, for $PSL(2,8)$,  it is a group of order $504$ which
has no subgroup of order $21$ or $504/21=24$ (the only problematic case regarding the note). Hence, we can check this special case by the GAP.

Comment: Then, as $G = \operatorname{PSL}(2, 11)$ has a subgroup $H \cong A_5$ of index $11$, $G$ enjoys **(P)**, right? I also see this doesn't work for $\operatorname{PSL}(2, 13)$.

Comment: That's right. Hence, we should check it in another way.

Comment: It seems that $PSL(2,13)$ is a counterexample to the stronger property because it has no subgroups of order $21$ or $52$. I just asked a question about this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573297/generating-psl2-13-with-two-subgroups-of-coprime-order

Comment: @EwanDelanoy The property is not stronger at all because $A$ and $B$ are _subsets_, not subgroups.

Comment: @Orat Yes it is. There are two properties here, $(P)$ as in the question, and another property (let us call it $(P')$) that says that $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$ or $\frac{n}{d}$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$. Now $(P')$ implies $(P)$, as stated in the question (it is easy to see why : take $A$ to be the subgroup and $B$ a set of representatives for the quotient group).  So $(P')$ is indeed stronger than $(P)$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Now I got your point. It seems, though, it is already known to OP as he mentioned that $\operatorname{PSL}(2, 8)$ does not satisfy ($P'$) but does satisfy ($P$) and asked if, specifically, $\operatorname{PSL}(2, 13)$ satisfies ($P$). If $\operatorname{PSL}(2, 13)$ does satisfy ($P'$), then he would not ask that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this can be generalized in any way, but for the $G=PSL_2(13)$ case, you can get sets $A$ and $B$ of sizes $21$ and $52$ with the property $G=AB$ by simply multiplying Sylow-$3$ and Sylow-$7$ subgroups for $A$ and Sylow-$2$ and Sylow-$13$ subgroups for $B$, as GAP shows:

```
gap> G:=PSL(2,13);;
gap> A := Concatenation(List(SylowSubgroup(G, 7), s -> AsList(RightCoset(SylowSubgroup(G, 3), s))));;
gap> B := Concatenation(List(SylowSubgroup(G, 13), s -> AsList(RightCoset(SylowSubgroup(G, 2), s))));;
gap> Size(G);
1092
gap> Size(A);
21
gap> Size(B);
52
gap> Size(Concatenation(List(A, a -> List(B, b -> a*b))));
1092
```